# Fill in the two blanks

Tags: rebus, word-property

Fill in the country names in the two boxes to make the equation correct.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you fill the first blank with:

> **INDONESIA**

Then:

> Remove the 1's (or the **ONES**)

You get:

> **INDIA**